# Why does a simple transition cost so much GPU resources?

Tags: css

I'm developing a simple music player. One thing I've noticed is that the GPU usage is unreasonably high despite the actual layout being pretty simple. After disabling various elements of the page, I've realized that the progress bar transition is what's causing this massive GPU usage.

[image: GPU usage]

It's weird because it seems so simple. Even if I do it in a Codepen, it's causing this massive GPU usage:

https://jsfiddle.net/bhn9sfux/

```js
let progressBar = document.getElementById("progressbar");
setTimeout(() => progressBar.style.width = "100%", 1000);
```

```css
#progressbar {
  background: black;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 60s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

My PC is reasonably beefy (RX Vega 56) and it can obviously still display it smoothly. That's not the problem. What's confusing me is how such a simple transition can even cause such a big performance consumption in the first place. I was expecting low 0-point numbers, and definitely no power consumption of "Middle" level.

Is my CSS terrible? Is there something I am overlooking about the render engine? Or is it simply how it is?

Comment: FWIW, it's barely even registering on my side (which is expected). macOS, M1 MBP, both in FF and in Chrome. You might want to try seeing if other CSS transitions have a massive impact on your performance, as well as if other browsers exhibit the same behavior on your machine.

Comment: Even on Chrome it still sits at around 2.5% throughout the animation. Again, I'm not sure if these numbers are normal, but they seem overkill for literally just displaying a progress bar

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's eating up so much GPU is because you're animating the `width` property.  When you change a value that effects the box dimensions, (And a handful of other properties) the DOM needs to re run a bunch of calculations, which causes a full Reflow of the DOM.  Which is quite expensive.

> #### [Reflow](https://www.hi-interactive.com/blog/avoid-reflow-repaint)
>
> By definition, “Reflow” is the process the web browser uses to
> re-calculate the positions and geometries of elements in the document.
> It’s basically the effort the browser needs to do to position every
> element in the screen every time something changes (either by a
> refresh, a screen resize or a common show/hide content action).

Try the animation using something like `clip-path`, or wrapping the progress bar in a parent container with `overflow: hidden;` and then move the progress bar with `transform: translate3d();`   This way the box doesn't change size, only position.

#### Here is a simple example using `clip-path`:

```css
.bar {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  animation: 1s infinite alternate slidein;
  clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Didn't know about clip-path. Unfortunately, however, I'm still averaging around 5% GPU load while this code snippet is playing, which is actually even bigger than my previous width solution...

Comment: As for the translate3d solution, I tried that, which only seems to take around 3.2% load, but it's still crazy high to me: https://jsfiddle.net/0s2mxcq8/

Maybe I should just accept that GPU load for CSS animations is always expensive, no matter how simple it is. It's just really boggling my mind how a simple progress bar could use so much power in the first place. It didn't really solve my problem, but your answer was the most thorough, so have the bounty :)

Comment: Interesting that it only went down 0.2%.  Now I want to investigate it further and see if there's a way to reduce that even more.

Comment: My intuition is that there's a good chunk of resources needed to run browser based animations, and that you can combine them without eating up much more than what a single one uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try will-change property of CSS if you are trying to reduce the GPU usage or else Use requestAnimationFrame This method can help synchronize rendering with the browser's internal animation loop, which can improve performance and reduce GPU usage.
What i have seen is its not about your code or progress bar its about SetTimeout().

Comment: I tried `will-change: width;`, but that had zero effect on the GPU load, unfortunately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).